# Find out the missing number in the diagram

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> Find out the missing number in the diagram
>
> [image]
>
> Options are
>
> $(A)$ 60
>
> $(B)$ 62
>
> $(C)$ 64
>
> $(D)$ 66

I've been thinking about problem all morning to no avail.

Can't seem to figure out the connection here. Help please!

This problem appeared in a national level civil services exam in India.

Comment: This type of questions make IMHO relatively poor material for our site. I came up with a somewhat arbitrary rule: the number in the middle must be smaller than the product of the two numbers at the ends of a line segment of an X, except if both of those two numbers are even, when the number in the middle must be larger than the product. $30$ is less than both $4\cdot9$ and $7\cdot5$, $50$ is less than $3\cdot17$ but larger than $6\cdot8$. So ? should be smaller than $3\cdot21$ but larger than $6\cdot10$, making $62$ the answer. The rule is unsatisfactory, but so?

Comment: Anyway, in the sample diagrams the products are in the ballpark of the number in the middle, so whatever the problem designer was thinking is likely related to that. The problem is that, just like with the "what's the next number of this sequence" -questions, we can cook up a "rule" that fits pretty much anything we want. Puzzling.SE is better for questions of this type IMHO.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen pretty interesting observation. I think the solution should involve some type of computation using the numbers in the corners to "obtain" the middle number. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am kind of confused. You see, the civil service exam consists of many of these questions to be answered in short time, so I think the time limit for a question like this is about 2-3 minutes. That is astonishing looking at the complexity of the rule we have come up with. So of course there may be something simpler involved here.

Comment: Well, I am prepared to be wrong :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it is more appropriately asked at [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

"Hint":

$$30=2(7+9)+(-1)^7+(-1)^9+(-1)^5+(-1)^4$$
and
$$50=2(17+8)+(-1)^{17}+(-1)^8+(-1)^3+(-1)^6$$

(I use scare quotes around "Hint" here to mean that this is one of many patterns one can attribute to the problem.  Note, the powers of $-1$ just means you add $1$ for each even number and subtract $1$ for each odd number.)

Comment: If it is this the answer, it is demoniac! I hate this kind of puzzle, but I hate more who says that the ability in solving these puzzles can weight intelligence